# União de vetores na linguagem C

Tags: c

Questão: Faça um programa que leia dois vetores de 10 elementos. Crie um vetor que seja a união entre os 2 vetores anteriores, ou seja, que contém os números dos dois vetores. Não deve conter números repetidos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int vetorA[10];
    int vetorB[10];
    int vetorAB[20];
    int ate = 0;


    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("Digite um valor para o vetorA[%d]:", i);
        scanf("%d",&vetorA[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        printf("Digite um valor para o vetorA[%d]:", j);
        scanf("%d",&vetorB[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++){
        vetorAB[k] = vetorA[k];
    }

    for(int v = 0; v < 10; v++){
        int achou = 0;
        for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++){
            if(vetorB[v] == vetorA[z]){
                achou = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(achou == 0){
            vetorAB[v+10] = vetorB[v];
            ate = ate + 1;
        }
    }
    for(int u = 0; u < 10 + ate; u++){
        printf("%d ", vetorAB[u]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Queria fazer união de vetores , o algoritmo começa colocando os valores do vetorA no vetorAB e depois devia testar os valores de B e os iguais não colocar no vetor da união alguém da um help aí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é algo bem pequenino, isto:

```
if(achou == 0){
    vetorAB[v+10] = vetorB[v];
    //      ^----
    ate = ate + 1;
}
```

Não pode guardar com base no `v`. Imaginando que o array `B` começa com 3 valores repetidos o primeiro a ser guardado ia para a casa `13` em vez de `10`, pois o `v` aumenta sempre quer guarda ou não. Tem de guardar com base no `ate` que simboliza a quantidade de elementos já guardada e consequentemente o ultimo:

```
if(achou == 0){
    vetorAB[10 + ate] = vetorB[v];
    //             ^----
    ate = ate + 1;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/GH6CBy)

A lógica que utilizou acabou por ficar um pouco complicada também, e também não funciona para o caso de o próprio array A já ter elementos repetidos.

Pode resolver também esse caso e manter o código simples se adicionar algumas funções para as operações que está a fazer.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void le_array(int arr[], int tam, char *texto){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("Digite um valor para o %s[%d]:", texto, i);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int existe(int arr[], int tam, int val){
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == val){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int vetorA[10], vetorB[10], vetorAB[20];
    int ate = 0;

    le_array(vetorA, 10, "vetorA");
    le_array(vetorB, 10, "vetorB");
    for(int v = 0; v < 10; v++){
        if (!existe(vetorAB, ate, vetorA[v])){
            vetorAB[ate++] = vetorA[v];
        }
    }
    for(int v = 0; v < 10; v++){
        if (!existe(vetorAB, ate, vetorB[v])){
            vetorAB[ate++] = vetorB[v];
        }
    }

    for(int u = 0; u < ate; u++){
        printf("%d ", vetorAB[u]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja esta solução também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/zbeuud)

Reparei também que trocou todas as variáveis do `for`, fazendo cada um com uma diferente. Isto não é necessário e pode usar a mesma em todos pois quando a declaração é feita dentro do `for` essa variável só existe dentro dele.

Comment: Mt obrigado valeu mesmo